# Problem with integrating Swagger in Spring Boot application - getting 404 error on accessing Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to integrate Swagger into my Spring Boot application. My spring boot version is 2.4.5. I have included the following dependencies in my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my Swagger configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

I've included annotation @EnableSwagger2 on my main class. This is my webSecurityClass:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Autowired
    private AppConfigProperties appConfigProperties;

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/temp").permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/v2/**", "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().csrf().disable();

        http.addFilterAfter(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            System.out.println("WebSecurityConfig coming here ---------> ");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
                        .allowedOrigins(appConfigProperties.getConfigValue("origin"));
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If I access the URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html, I get the response:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 01 19:10:32 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

If I access the URL http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html, I get the following response:

```
Unable to infer base URL. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base URL is the root of where all the Swagger resources are served. For example, if the API is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs, then the base URL is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:
```

What is wrong with my configuration? I tried many things but it is not working. If I call http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs through Postman, it's working.

Comment: `If I call http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs through Postman, it's working`, it probably you didn't set cors properly because postman doesn't send a cors request compared to browser.

Comment: This url is even working on the browser: http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs
The UI is not working: I tried, localhost:8080/swagger-ui/, /swagger-ui.html, /swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`springfox` does not work properly when used with spring-boot version greater than 2.4. I faced the same error and fixed it by using `springdocs` instead of `springfox`.
You can remove `springfox` dependency from `pom.xml` and use below instead-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You can remove `@EnableSwagger2` annotation as well.
The API docs can be accessed on `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

Comment: If we have security enabled like JWT token, we need to add this:

@Bean public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .components(new Components()
            .addSecuritySchemes("bearerScheme", new SecurityScheme()
                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                .scheme("bearer")
                .bearerFormat("JWT"))
        )
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("bearerScheme"));
    // This applies the security globally (padlock icon on all end points)
}